# C++ Share memory and call functions in one executable from another executable?

Tags: c++

This is probably a basic question but I'm new to C++ and I can't find the answer online, I think because I don't know what to search for exactly.

For my project I have a data structure that will be in C++, it's essentially a really big 3D model many GB in size stored in memory. I've written a program to store and manipulate this massive 3D model.

I would like for third-parties to be able to write their own compiled executables that link into my own executable and can call certain functions on it directly, for example to render the 3D model, without having to serialize data and pass it back and forth. So basically I want a third party executable to be able to connect or link to my executable, so they operate kind of like my program is a library that is part of that program, even though its actually a separate running process. They should be able to call functions and perhaps even (if allowed) access memory from my process (can I pass a reference to a memory location and they use that reference like its their own?) Can variables in the heap be shared across programs? Can functions be called in one process by another running process?

Does that make sense?
Where do I look to learn how to do this?

Comment: You're looking for IPC (inter process communication). There are multiple ways of doing this and the way you achieve it depends on the operating system. Based on your question you should start looking into shared memory.